# How to input coordinates values from a multi-value hashmap into javafx point2d?

Tags: java, javafx

Currently, I am trying to create a heatmap using JavaFX, and I have stored the country name and its coordinates into a `HashMap`. My idea was to call the `HashMap` and get the coordinates value of the countries into `Point2D`. Such that I could maybe loop the line `events = new Point2D[]`, rather than writing the new points individually. I'm not sure if my thoughts of coding are correct. However, there was an error (as shown in the code below).

> The constructor Point2D(List) is undefined

How can I get the coordinates value in the `HashMap` and input into `Point2D`, rather then inserting the value itself into `Point2D` (as shown in the code below) ?

```
@Override public void init() {
    //Setting country coordinates on the map
    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> countryCoordinates = new HashMap<>();
    Integer[] coordinates = {};
    countryCoordinates.put("china", Arrays.asList(700, 180));
    countryCoordinates.put("Diamond Princess", Arrays.asList(810, 170));
    countryCoordinates.put("Singapore", Arrays.asList(726, 310));
    countryCoordinates.put("Japan", Arrays.asList(810, 170));
    countryCoordinates.put("Hong Kong", Arrays.asList(755, 225));
    countryCoordinates.put("Thailand", Arrays.asList(720, 250));
    .
    .
    .
    .
    pane = new StackPane();
    heatMap = new SimpleHeatMap(1000, 600, ColorMapping.LIME_YELLOW_RED, 40);
    heatMap.setOpacityDistribution(OpacityDistribution.EXPONENTIAL);
    heatMap.setHeatMapOpacity(1);
    events  = new Point2D[] {
        new Point2D(countryCoordinates.get("china")), //The constructor Point2D(List<Integer>) is undefined
        new Point2D(810, 170),
```

Comment: Class `Point2D` only has one [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Point2D.html#Point2D-double-double-). You could create a class that extends `Point2D` and add another constructor, i.e. one that accepts a `List`.

Comment: so something like
public Point2DList(List<Integer>));
?

Comment: Class declaration example: `public class My2dPoint extends Point2D` and constructor example: `public My2dPoint(List<Integer> coords)`

Comment: thanks, one more question, I tried out creating another class extending to Point2D and create another constructor. However, I receive this following error "Implicit super constructor Point2D() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor"

Comment: A subclass here seems overkill: all it would provide would be an additional constructor (no additional functionality or state). Just define a method that takes a `List<Integer>` and returns a `Point2D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each list is size 2 (which appears to be true from the code you posted), all you would need to do to convert a single element of your map to a `Point2D` is extract the two elements from the list and pass them to the `Point2D` constructor:

```
List<Integer> chinaCoords = countryCoordinates.get("china");
Point2D chinaPoint = new Point2D(chinaCoords.get(0), chinaCoords.get(1));
```

Since you're doing this repeatedly, instead of writing this code repeatedly, it's probably more convenient to define a utility method to do it:

```
private Point2D asPoint2D(List<Integer> coordList) {
    return new Point2D(coordList.get(0), coordList.get(1));
}
```

And then the code in your `init()` method just looks like

```
events = new Point2D[] {
    asPoint2D(countryCoordinates.get("china")),
    ...
};
```

---

More advanced (but cleaner) option:

If you're familiar with the Streams API and lambda expressions, you can even do this without defining an explicit function (or explicit loops, etc):

```
events = countryCoordinates().values().stream()
    .map(list -> new Point2D(list.get(0), list.get(1)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .toArray(new Point2D[countryCoordinates.size()]);
```

Comment: So I need to repeat the first code cause it is not just china ?

Comment: @DeniseTay Define the method once, then replace `...` with the repeated code for the other countries.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was the
List<Integer> chinaCoords = countryCoordinates.get("china");
Point2D chinaPoint = new Point2D(chinaCoords.get(0), chinaCoords.get(1));

Do i need to repeat this as well ?

Comment: @DeniseTay You don't need that at all. It was just to illustrate the idea.

Comment: ah I see thanks, but is there a way to loop the events = new Point2D[] ? instead of me copy and paste the repeated code for other countries ?

Comment: Yes, just iterate over `countryCoordinates.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using Java's [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) which creates an array of `Point2D` objects - since it appears, from the code in your question, that's what you want to do.

```java
Map<String, List<Integer>> countryCoordinates = new HashMap<>();
countryCoordinates.put("china", Arrays.asList(700, 180));
countryCoordinates.put("Diamond Princess", Arrays.asList(810, 170));
countryCoordinates.put("Singapore", Arrays.asList(726, 310));
countryCoordinates.put("Japan", Arrays.asList(810, 170));
countryCoordinates.put("Hong Kong", Arrays.asList(755, 225));
countryCoordinates.put("Thailand", Arrays.asList(720, 250));
List<Point2D> pts = countryCoordinates.values()
                                      .stream()
                                      .map(lst -> new Point2D(lst.get(0), lst.get(1)))
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
Point2D[] points = pts.toArray(new Point2D[]{});
```